# Path with one square angle

Tags: c#, algorithm

I would like to know how to create an algorithm to solve the following problem.
In this picture below, I have a matrix with 0, 1 and negative 1. Negative 1 are my start point and my target point. I have develop a flood fill algorith which not working correctly. In fact it gives me the shortest path.
It check the free space (0) in north, east, west and south.

```
matrix[x+1, y]
matrix[x-1, y]
matrix[x, y+1]
matrix[x, y-1]
```

It create the blue path, and not working as I want.
I would like to create the path in Red.
Do you known how I can realize this kind of algorithm ?

In this example the direction is North West.

[image]

Comment: Show the algorithm that you are following. Also, what does the red-path signify? The shortest path? There can be more than one shortest paths.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal The red-path is a functionnal path, not the shortest path.

Comment: You might have to add a weight to changing direction - that way the simpler path will be chosen over the just-as-long complicated path. A* isn't very useful for this kind of search. If you're only looking for a path that's only ever composed of two lines, you're probably using a way too complicated path search algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're really after a flood fill algorithm, you're overly complicating things I think.

A relatively simple and fast algorithm can be found here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16405/Queue-Linear-Flood-Fill-A-Fast-Flood-Fill-Algorith

It's quite easy to implement a workable recursive flood fill if you don't expect to be filling all too many tiles / pixels. Wikipedia also has tons of algorithms:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Usually you either use a stack or a queue to keep track of the non-rectangular regions in the target "image" and fill either line-by-line, or in a "diamond" pattern (first try the 4 directions from the current pixel, enqueue those that were filled).

Your question doesn't fit SO all that well :)